# Telethon bot does not work when launched from systemd

Tags: systemd, telethon

here is the config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/shutova.service
  GNU nano 4.8                                                /etc/systemd/system/shutova.service
[Unit]
Description=Shutova
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=django
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/django/Shutova_assist/bot.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I use

```
python3 bot.py
```

everything works without problems.
When I start systemd:

```
sudo systemctl start shutova
```

Status - active, but when communicating with the bot, I do not receive answers.
there are no errors in the log either.

Please tell me what could be the matter?

(I tried to run as root python3 bot.py, it runs without errors)

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly someone one day will face such a problem. The answer was in the library telethon which uses the session. It is necessary in the config when starting on the server to immediately specify the full path to the current session (before that, log in interactively).
Here is the piece of code that solved my problem:

```
client = TelegramClient('/full/path/to/my.session', telegram_api_id, telegram_api_hash)
```